# How to detect intersections of two faces of two bufferGeometryBox?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am developing a 3d configurator. A cube appears on the scene. If you click on the side of this cube, a rectangle appears. The problem is that if I click on the same side of the cube, another one will be added over the existing rectangle. I would like to block the clicked side. My cubes and rectangles is buffer geometry. I can get raycasting face (a,b,c) and faceIndex. But how to get intersection of two different faces of two different objects? Sorry for my english

This is my project https://alovert.ru

[image]
[image]
[image]

my code

```
if (intersect) {
            var index = Math.floor( intersect.faceIndex / 6 );
                if ( intersect.object.name == 'cube' ) {

                    switch ( index ) {
                        case 0: load( intersect.object.position.x + 6.58, intersect.object.position.y, intersect.object.position.z, 'beam', 0, 0, 0 ); break;
                        case 1: load( intersect.object.position.x - 6.58, intersect.object.position.y, intersect.object.position.z, 'beam', 0, 0, 0 ); break;
                        case 2: load( intersect.object.position.x, intersect.object.position.y + 6.58, intersect.object.position.z, 'beam', 0, 0, 90 ); break;
                        case 3: load( intersect.object.position.x, intersect.object.position.y - 6.58, intersect.object.position.z, 'beam', 0, 0, 90 ); break;
                        case 4: load( intersect.object.position.x, intersect.object.position.y, intersect.object.position.z + 6.58, 'beam', 0, 90, 0 ); break;
                        case 5: load( intersect.object.position.x, intersect.object.position.y, intersect.object.position.z - 6.58, 'beam', 0, 90, 0 ); break;
                    }

                }`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it can be useful for people have the same problem.
The main idea is to create rectangle and cubes with userData, that have 6 parameters “false”. From every face i cast a ray and if it intersect face from other object, this face became “true”. [Click](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/how-to-check-if-ray-don-t-intersect-the-face-more/8263)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that the newly created object that is duplicated will have the same global position (check [this](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Object3D.getWorldPosition)) value as the already existing one. So you can simply traverse over the existing objects and compare their positions, if they match or have a minor difference in position values, then block.

To make things faster, you can keep the objects global position values in a list once they are created and iterate over the list instead.

Comment: Hi! Could you explain a bit more? Unfortunatly i dont understand how it must work

Comment: please see my other answer

Answer (score 1):

see the following meta-code that describes the idea:

```
let newObject = loadObject(...);
parentObj.add(newObject);
newObject.position.set(new_x, new_y, new_z);
let globalPosition = new THREE.Vector3();
newObject.getWorldPosition(globalPosition);
for (let i = 0; i < existingPositions.length; i++){
    if(     existingPositions[i].x === globalPosition.x
        &&  existingPositions[i].y === globalPosition.y
        &&  existingPositions[i].z === globalPosition.z) {
            parentObj.remove(newObject);
            return;
    }
}
existingPositions.push(globalPosition);
```

Comment: Hi ! Sorry for delay, i resolved my problem by piece of code in this article https://discourse.threejs.org/t/how-to-check-if-ray-don-t-intersect-the-face-more/8263